# How to compare correlations between experimental groups?

Tags: correlation, likert

I have tested an education intervention and have a control and an experimental group.

I have administered a survey and would like to know if the correlations among the survey statements are different in control vs. experimental. I have about 30 statements. It is Likert scale and I have already done Spearman's. But not sure how to interpret it as a lot of statements are significantly correlated (even if low). I decided to only look for correlations >0.6 and compare those but not sure if I can actually do that.

Are there other methods to compare correlations of the survey statements between control and experimental? Sample size for each group is 40.

Comment: What research question would you like to answer from comparing these correlation estimates?

Comment: Would [canonical correlation analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canonical_correlation) on the ranks of your data be appropriate? It allows comparison of two datasets with compatible data table (matrix) shapes.